# Xstream date attribute

Tags: java, xstream

I want to format the date attribute in my xstream output, i created a date converter which converts tot eh right format however, it creates a new sub-element rather than adding tot he parent element attribute.

I want the following

When i register a date converter for the Date.class.. I get the following:

```
<output>
<date>20/11/2012</date>
```

Also having problems with offset there seems to be a difference in actual dates when parsed, for instance... if i parse 20/11/2012 10.30 as the current time.. what gets output is 20/11/2012 10.12... or something different.. do i need to do some conversion or offset?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created this... seems to do what i want

```
private DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/Y HH:mm:ss");

    public boolean canConvert(Class type) {
        return type.equals(Date.class);
    }

    public Object fromString(String str) {      
        DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(str);
        return dt.toDate();
    }

    public String toString(Object obj) {        
        return fmt.print(((Date) obj).getTime());
    }
```